# How does the betting work for the races in GTA V Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Whenever you bet around $2500 with two or three people, you get $1000 profit. I just don't understand how this works.  If anyone could help, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the winning odds. You can see them before the race in the player list, after selecting your car. Players with high win rates have lower odds and vice versa.

If you were getting $1000 on top of your initial $2500, it means that the odds of the player you bet on were 2/5. If you placed your bet on a player with 3/1 odds, you'd triple your wager.

Comment: That's strange. [Real bookie odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds#Gambling_odds_versus_probabilities) mean that winning gets you back your stake plus the payout, so winning 2/5 should be $2500 (stake) + $1000 (payout) = $3500 returned. Or is the game's feedback confusing and it just doesn't mention that you're keeping/getting back your stake?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Thanks, that's what I meant, I rephrased my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

just depends on the players odds you bet on. if you bet more than $2000 on a player with 33-1 odds (which is like most new players vs experienced ones) you could make a killing up to 30 grand plus just in one race. sometimes i try to take wreck the good players during races to enable the ones i bet on have a fighting chance so i can get high returns. i also make sure a finish the race so i can get paid also :) very nice way to earn quick cash. you usually see what you win after the person who you bet on comes first. the game credits you as they cross the finish line. just notice the screen.

Comment: So theoretically, you could get 2 friends together (3 is minimum for betting), lose a bunch of races (or just really suck to begin with) to get your odds down. Then the three of you switch off letting each other win and betting on that person full pop. Since you switch off, the odds would stay the same and you'd get the extra cash.